# Extending the std::priority_queue functionality

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to implement a priority queue in such a way that every time I push a new item or pop an item from the queue a function is executed, for example add or subtract each items "error" to the global "error".

Is there some neat **standard** way to achieve this? Below is a simplified example where I have solved it be having a struct that "wraps" the std::priority_queue. I'm a novice C++ programmer and hence I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution.

```
#include <queue>

struct myStruct {
    double Error;
    friend bool operator<(const myStruct& lhs, const myStruct& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Error < rhs.Error;
    }
};

typedef std::priority_queue < myStruct, std::vector<myStruct>, std::less<myStruct>> StdQueue;

struct priorityQueue {
    priorityQueue() { Error = 0; }
    StdQueue queue;
    double Error;

    void push(myStruct s)
    {
        Error += s.Error;
        queue.push(s);
    }

    void pop()
    {
        Error -= queue.top().Error;
        queue.pop();
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should be posted to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz CR.SE requires a full working example.  I think this question is OK on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike actual containers the [container adaptors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Container_adaptors) are actually designed to be inheritable. For example, if you look at e.g. [this `std::priority_queue` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) you will see that it has [`protected` member objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue#Member_objects).

That means you can inherit from `std::priority_queue` and create your own `pop` and `push` functions to do what you want before calling the actual queues functions.

As noted by skypack in a comment the functions are not `virtual`, which means you can't use polymorphism with your inherited class. You can't really pass it to functions expecting a `std::priority_queue`, the code has to be explicitly use your class.

Comment: Even if adaptors expose members to derived classes, `pop` and `push` are not declared `virtual`. This is something to which to pay attention if one wants to inherit from `std::priority_queue`. Polymorphism is not for free.